# Un-enqueue styles for certain built-in Gutenberg block types?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, block-editor

Is it possible to un-enqueue stylesheets for the built-in Gutenberg block types?

e.g. I would like to add custom styles for the Gutenberg Columns block, so I'd like to un-enqueue the stylesheets just for this block type, but keep the default styles for the others.

Answer (score 1):

In Gutenberg and plugins for Gutenberg are all styles involved via `wp_enqueue_style`. I would to see all developers use [`wp_register_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) before, makes easier to deregister. However you should un-enqueue the style via the core function [`wp_dequeue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/).

So this should work, in dependency of the hook and handle of the style and his handle, here for example `gutenberg-handle-foo`.

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', function() {
    wp_dequeue_style('gutenberg-handle-foo');
}, 99);
```

#### A screenshot

about handle examaples in the WP Admin Edit Post screen, version 5.2 of WP.

[image]

Comment: Any idea where I might find the handle for the core blocks?

Comment: Yes, the plugin Query Monitor has a feature to list all blocks, there are installed, see https://twitter.com/johnbillion/status/1071563623280070656

Comment: Does this actually work? Gutenberg enqueues a single CSS file containing styles for all its core blocks, so I don't think it is possible to dequeue/enqueue styles for a single block.

Comment: I mean yes, but not tested. However lot of handles are still existent, see the screenshot above.